# How to check object exists or not in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, t-sql, psql

We can check whether object exist or not in T-SQL using following query.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TBL_COMP_ASSESSMENT') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TBL_COMP_ASSESSMENT
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Oracle?

Answer (score 7):

It is a bad idea to **DROP** and **CREATE** tables on the fly. **T-SQL** and **PL/SQL** are very different. PL/SQL is compiled prior to execution and reside in database. What you do in T-SQL might not be good in PL/SQL. You could **TRUNCATE** the table rather than dropping it on the fly.

Anyway, if you really want to do it, then you need to (ab)use **EXECUTE IMMEDIATE** to do this.

For example,

```
SQL>  DECLARE
  2      cnt NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4      SELECT Count(*)
  5      INTO   cnt
  6      FROM   user_tables
  7      WHERE  table_name = 'TBL_COMP_ASSESSMENT';
  8
  9      IF cnt = 1 THEN
 10        BEGIN
 11            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE TBL_COMP_ASSESSMENT';
 12        EXCEPTION
 13            WHEN OTHERS THEN
 14              IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
 15                RAISE;
 16              END IF;
 17        END;
 18      END IF;
 19  END;
 20
 21  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use ALL_OBJECTS table. Something like this should do:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_NAME = '<OBJ_NAME_HERE>'
```

You can add more conditions as per your requirement:

```
AND OWNER='<OWNER>' AND OBJECT_TYPE='<TYPE>'
```

Full details here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2005.htm

Answer (score 1):

you can check it using

```
  begin    
  if ObjType = 'TABLE' then
    select count(*) into v_counter from user_tables where table_name = upper(ObjName);
    if v_counter > 0 then          
      execute immediate 'drop table ' || ObjName || ' cascade constraints';        
    end if;   
  end if;
   end;
```